# callback function from an async workflow f#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm in a little bit of a pickle here. I can't seem to make async workflow to callback at each step of a computation. Here's my code

```
let criteria: state -> state -> bool = ...//criteria definition
let callback: state -> unit = ..../callback definition
let rec compute task state =
    async{
      ....// some long computations
      let task' = task.ContinueWith(fun _ ->callback(newState))
      if criteria state newState then return newState
      else return! compute task' newState
    }
```

Comment: Where does `newState` come from?

Comment: Wild guess - but maybe try using `Async.AwaitTask` to call the task?

Comment: Hard to tell what you're expecting.  As written, your `compute` loop is run independently of your tasks. So each loop through `compute` will add another task to the queue, but it's not going to wait for those tasks to end.  Give some more context behind what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DaxFohl well, I'm trying to create a diagnositc callback each time i have finished computing the new state and the method shouldn't wait for diagnostic call

Comment: I made some dummy implementations to fill out your code, and the result works for me.  The async task runs to completion and the diagnostic calls all eventually get executed:  https://gist.github.com/daxfohl/98e00169aca1f0a2828f1135e812302e

Comment: maybe it was my mistake to use Task constructor rather than Task.Run

Comment: tks for your help :D

Comment: @JokingBear That's likely true - `Task` constructor is something you should never really use - it creates a cold task, which is discouraged, as nothing will start it.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Rather than using a `Task` and adding continuations to it, it may be more idiomatic here to use a `MailboxProcessor` anyway.